# Viewport device-width is double the width

Tags: mobile, jquery-mobile

I have a mobile website which is design on 640px wide. So all content is a maximum of 640px wide.

In the header I have my meta tag:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
```

On iPhone/iPad/iPodtouch the page is displayed correctly: the content fits exactly the width of the screen. But when I try it on Android (default browser or Dolphin HD) the screen is exactly half, so 320px wide. Very annoying because then you have to manually zoom out the see all the content.

How can I make sure that on load ALL content is always shown?

Answer (score 0):

Try specifying the target-densityDpi:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, target-densityDpi=device-dpi">
```